# What's the values for the Freq_Interval column in MSDB.dbo.SysSchedules when Freq_Type is weekly and more than one day is selected in the schedule?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, jobs, system-tables

I'm reading up on the [SysSchedules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysschedules-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) table in the Microsoft API, and am trying to incorporate using this table in a query.

In the documentation, the Freq_Interval column seems to be defined out for when a single day is selected in the schedule and the Freq_Type is weekly.
But what are the values for every other combination of days when more than one day is selected?

For example, I have a job which is scheduled to occur weekly on the days Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday.
I see in the MSDB.dbo.SysSchedules table, it has a Freq_Interval of 62 (which isn't listed in the documentation.)

[image: Job Schedule Details]
[image: MSDB.dbo.SysSchedules]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation states

> freq_interval is **one or more** of the following:
>
> 1 = Sunday 
> 2 = Monday 
> 4 = Tuesday 
> 8 = Wednesday 
> 16 = Thursday 
> 32 = Friday 
> 64 = Saturday

These values are all powers of 2.

When you select multiple days simply add the distinct codes.

```
2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 = 62
```

or alternatively use the [bitwise or](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-or-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) operator to combine them.

```
2 | 4 | 8 | 16 | 32
```

(my recommendation would be to use `|` in code and `+` if adding them up in your head! - `|` is the "correct" thing to use and won't behave incorrectly if you have duplicate values in the list)

If you are trying to do the reverse operation you need [bitwise and](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
DECLARE @Sunday TINYINT = 1,
        @Monday TINYINT = 2,
        @Tuesday TINYINT = 4,
        @Wednesday TINYINT = 8,
        @Thursday TINYINT = 16,
        @Friday TINYINT = 32,
        @Saturday TINYINT = 64;

DECLARE @TestValue TINYINT = 62;

SELECT CASE WHEN @TestValue & @Sunday = @Sunday THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Sunday,
       CASE WHEN @TestValue & @Monday = @Monday THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Monday,
       CASE WHEN @TestValue & @Tuesday = @Tuesday THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Tuesday,
       CASE WHEN @TestValue & @Wednesday = @Wednesday THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Wednesday,
       CASE WHEN @TestValue & @Thursday = @Thursday THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Thursday,
       CASE WHEN @TestValue & @Friday = @Friday THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Friday,
       CASE WHEN @TestValue & @Saturday = @Saturday THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Saturday
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you! When I first saw how they spaced out that enum I was wondering if it was something like a bitwise operation. But I'm not super experienced using that type of operation and didn't think much more into it. Cool that'll work though, thanks.